Anonymous PL/SQL block error in Pro*C but not in SQL Developer: CSF-S-00201, identifier 'RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR' must be declared
In a Pro*C file, I have a very straightforward anonymous PL/SQL block like this:
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
     unsigned long long stuff = 0;
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

EXEC SQL EXECUTE
DECLARE
    nrows pls_integer := 0;
BEGIN
    select count(*) into nrows from tbl;

    if nrows != 1 then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,
                    'The table must contain exactly one row');
    else
        select stuff into :stuff FROM tbl;
    end if;
END; 
END-EXEC;

Pro*C protests with:
CSF-S-00201, identifier 'RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR' must be declared

However, moving the anonymous PL/SQL block to the SQL developer (and adding a stuff variable):
VARIABLE stuff NUMBER;

DECLARE
    nrows pls_integer := 0;
BEGIN
    select count(*) into nrows from tbl;

    if nrows != 1 then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,
                    'The table must contain exactly one row');
    else
        select stuff into :stuff FROM tbl;
    end if;
END;
/

works fine. What could be going on? The schema I'm using to compile the Pro*C file and to execute the block in SQL developer is the same.
I have set the following options:
sqlcheck=semantics
parse=partial
code=cpp
common_parser=yes

sqlcheck=semantics is mandatory if the file contains PL/SQL blocks, I have tried to remove common_parser=yes but the error is the same, and I can't remove parse=partial and code=cpp, but I don't think it would affect it whatsoever.

did you specify SQLCHECK=SEMANTICS when pre-compiling?

@gsalem Yes, otherwise Pro*C says something like: "you have to specify sqlcheck=semantics if your program contains pl/sql blocks".

Your code works in the database fiddle (although you could streamline it to use only a single SELECT by catching the NO_DATA_FOUND and TOO_MANY_ROWS exceptions). You can try replacing RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(...); with RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND; just to raise a different exception and see if it is that function causing the issue but I don't see why it would be that.

Or even more simply BEGIN select stuff into :stuff FROM tbl; END; and just let the SELECT raise either NO_DATA_FOUND or TOO_MANY_ROWS exceptions if there is not a single row. (You wouldn't get your custom error message but I'm sure you can catch the exceptions in Pro*C and re-raise the correct exception.)

Not entirely sure why it's necessary, but you can avoid the error by explicitly referring to the DBMS_STANDARD package:
    if nrows != 1 then
        DBMS_STANDARD.RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,
                    'The table must contain exactly one row');

The PL/SQL reference mentions that

You can reference identifiers declared in the packages STANDARD and DBMS_STANDARD without qualifying them with the package names, unless you have declared a local identifier with the same name

but that isn't the case from Pro*C.
